# Problems in Integrating Custom Favicon in Next.js Project Using JSX

Tags: next.js, favicon

[folder structure and new ico file image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IQ1r6.png)

I'm working on a Next.js project where I'm using JSX instead of TSX. I want to set a custom favicon for my website and ensure it appears correctly across all pages. However, I'm unsure about the proper integration process, especially considering I have separate layout and page components.

Here are the specifics:
I'm using JSX instead of TSX in my Next.js project.
I have separate layout (layout.jsx) and page (page.jsx) components.
I want to set a custom favicon for my website.
I've generated favicon files in ICO, PNG, and SVG formats.

I have tried every available solution but its still the same as always. Any proper solution would be appreaciable. Thank you.

[image: screenshot of invisibility of favicon regarding the issue]

Comment: Please share your project folder structure.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution :**

In your project, under app there will be default `favicon.ico` file, replace that with your custom favicon.ico file. Keep your favicon.ico file name as `favicon.ico`. The favicon image can only be located in the top level of `app/`.

**Location :** `app/favicon.ico`

```
app
├── favicon.ico
```

After replacing, clear history of browser & refresh page.

**Please Read :**

- **Favicon :** https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/file-conventions/metadata/app-icons

> ***If you have any doubts, then please leave a comment (I will update answer if necessary)***

Comment: actually i did the same what you suggested and when i replaced my own favicon.ico file, the original favicon icon of next.js disappeared and instead of showing my own its just got empty / no favicon. im sharing my folder structure with a screenshot edit in main question up there.

Comment: Stop the server, then clear browser history (everything) & re-run the project. On my-side it works properly just by  clearing everything from browser history. I have not added any head tags to specify favicons.

Comment: At last you may, *take a full project backup (this is just for safety, keep in another folder outside of your project)*, then delete `.next` folder & run the project.